# How can I replace unique vector elements based on order of occurrence?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, numeric

Let's say that I have this df (but so much bigger)

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(1:10,each=2) )
```

I wish this dataframe to become as follows (the objective is that I don't want to replace each value by its homologue. I want to find a way to replace all of these 10 values with their homologues as they are available.)

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(c(10,88,56,41,19,35,41,26,17,61),each=2))
```

```
    x
1  10
2  10
3  88
4  88
5  56
6  56
7  41
8  41
9  19
10 19
11 35
12 35
13 41
14 41
15 26
16 26
17 17
18 17
19 61
20 61
```

Comment: Is there a logic in 10, 88, 56, 41, 26...?

Comment: no they are just random

Comment: maybe: `library(dplyr) homologues <- c(10,88,56,41,19,35,41,26,17,61)  df %>% 
  mutate(x = rep(homologues, each=2))`

Comment: I tried editing your title to make it a bit clearer for future viewers, but still not sure I fully understand your goal. Did I capture it, or if not could you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do? Not sure I understand what you mean by "homologues."

```
homologues <- c(10,88,56,41,19,35,41,26,17,61)
df$x <- homologues[df$x]
```

Or possibly:

```
names(homologues) <- unique(df$x)
df$x <- homologues[as.character(df$x)]
```

Result in either case:

```
    x
1  10
2  10
3  88
4  88
5  56
6  56
7  41
8  41
9  19
10 19
11 35
12 35
13 41
14 41
15 26
16 26
17 17
18 17
19 61
20 61
```

Answer (score 2):

With `match` (this does not rely on the fact that `df$x` is `1:10` in the first place):

```r
lookup = setNames(c(10,88,56,41,19,35,41,26,17,61), unique(df$x))
df$x <- lookup[match(df$x, names(lookup))]
# [1] 10 10 88 88 56 56 41 41 19 19 35 35 41 41 26 26 17 17 61 61
```